# nested looping in android

Tags: for-loop

I am having an array of images.
I need to display 3 images in a row and then the next in another row.
How to do this using nested for loops. can anyone help me over this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic nested loop structure looks like this:

```
int imageIndex = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++ {
        // Draw your image here at x position of (column * image width)
        // and y position of (row * image height). Add a bit to each if you
        // want some spacing between your images.
        // For example:
        drawMyImage(images[imageIndex++], column * imageWidth, row * imageHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) with 3 columns.

```
<GridView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops.
The outer loop is for the rows. Each element in the row corresponds with a column, so the inner loop is for the columns.